# How could Pavel give up Shaw's weapon?

Tags: tron-uprising

In [01x07 Price of Power](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON:_Uprising_S01E07_Price_of_Power), a Disc upgrade created by the scientist Shaw was introduced, which while granting great power also pretty much clouded its bearer's mind - Beck could barely stop himself from

> derezzing Tron.

Then, in [01x17 Rendezvous](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Tron:_Uprising_S01E17_Rendezvous), Pavel is shown to use

> the regenerated upgrade first on prisoners and later against Paige.

He very clearly didn't intend to give it up at any point there, yet at the end of that episode,

> he gave it to Tesla (claiming to only having wanted to check its functionality first) (in addition to allegedly having figured out that the Renegade framed Paige (while really, *Pavel* did so)).

**Why?**

Shaw, a probably brilliant scientist, got consumed by his desire to retrieve the weapon from the Renegade, and as mentioned before Beck probably only managed to give it up because he almost

> derezzed Tron,

which, as Tron explained, means while the weapon does cloud judgement, it cannot change your basic nature. Yet, Pavel has previously more than once shown Paige that he intends to

> replace Tesla, with or without her assistance (he even offered her an alliance at some point before),

to which his actions at the end of Rendezvous seem pretty counter-productive.